# Unable to resolve contract folder on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cleos, eosio-code

My test contract cpp file is in  `/home/boby/hackathon/contracts/test/`     folder,  when I run

```
cleos set contract bob  /home/boby/hackathon/contracts/test/ -p bob@active
```

I get an error

> unable to resolve path  /home/boby/hackathon/contracts/test

What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try without the last slash in the path maybe?

Comment: the problem persists

Comment: I am on virtual machine, could this be problem?

Comment: I've built on VM before without issues.  Perhaps try setting a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Comment: relative path not very sure of what it is in this case

Comment: To find out the relative path, use 'pwd' to Print Working Directory, that is the directory you're in. If you want to make sure you're at the home directory, do: 'cd ~' Then you can use ./hackathon/contracts/test

Comment: Go to your 'test` folder and you don't need to add permission while setting contracts you  just have  to  do like this : `cleos set contract bob ./test` you don't need to define path of .abi and .wast if they are in same folder.

Comment: Can you show us the result of the command `ls  /home/boby/hackathon/contracts/test`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directory name and file names are same. For example, you have stored your files in a directory named test. So that, the contract files should be `test.cpp`, `test.hpp`, `test.wasm`, `test.wast` and `test.abi`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that in `/home/boby/hackathon/contracts/test/` folder，there exists `your_contrat_name.wasm` and `your_contract_name.abi` (`bob.wasm` `bob.abi`) file.